# I cannot get a Python Websocket listener to listen and print a Micropython Client send call. I can make it work Python client to Python Server

Tags: websocket, client, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico, usocket

I'm trying to have a Raspberry Pi Pico W read temp and other measurements and send via web socket to a server, which is a Raspberry Pi 4). The server, at this point, just prints the data out on the screen. I can make this work from one computer to another using a Python Client and a Python Web Server that's listening. I can't seem to make it work for a Micropython client with the same Python server. I don't get any errors and I get a response with the number of bytes from the server, but the server side code doesn't print the data.

So when I run the client code at the bottom (the one from python) the server prints the code to the shell. When I run the Micropython client, the server does not print the code to the shell. There's no error and it returns the correct number of bytes. I'm thinking I need an additional setting on the server side?

**Client Side Code is (running from a Raspberry Pi Pico W**

```
import time
import network
import usocket






ssid = 'WifiNetwork'
password = '12345'

wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
wlan.active(True)
wlan.connect(ssid, password)

# Wait for connect or fail
max_wait = 10
while max_wait > 0:
    if wlan.status() < 0 or wlan.status() >= 3:
        break
    max_wait -= 1
    print('waiting for connection...')
    time.sleep(1)

# Handle connection error
if wlan.status() != 3:
    raise RuntimeError('network connection failed')
else:
    print("Connected")
        
    #print('connected')
    status = wlan.ifconfig()
    print( 'Connected to ' + ssid + '. ' + 'Device IP: ' + status[0] )
    
    

sock = usocket.socket()
sockaddr = usocket.getaddrinfo('10.7.20.162', 8000)[0][-1]
print(sockaddr)
sock.connect(sockaddr)
sock.setblocking(False)

msg = 'Hello World from Pico'
resp = sock.send(bytes("Hello From Pico", "utf8"))
sock.sendall(msg)
sock.send(msg.encode())
print(resp)
sock.close()
```

**Server Side Code (Running from a Rapsberry Pi 4, Python)**

```
import websockets
import asyncio

# Server data
PORT = 8000
print("Server listening on Port " + str(PORT))

# A set of connected ws clients
connected = set()

# The main behavior function for this server
async def echo(websocket, path):
    print("A client just connected")
    # Store a copy of the connected client
    connected.add(websocket)
    # Handle incoming messages
    try:
        async for message in websocket:
            print("Received message from client: " + message)
            # Send a response to all connected clients except sender
            for conn in connected:
                if conn != websocket:
                    await conn.send("Someone said: " + message)
    # Handle disconnecting clients
    except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed as e:
        print("A client just disconnected")
    finally:
        connected.remove(websocket)

# Start the server
start_server = websockets.serve(echo, "10.7.20.162", PORT)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

**I can make this work with a client run in python, and that code is:**

```
import asyncio
import websockets
 
async def test():
    async with websockets.connect('ws://10.7.20.162:8000') as websocket:
        await websocket.send("Studio Temp 86")
    
 
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(test())
```

I can make this work with Python client code and the Python server code prints it to the shell (print() statement).

When I try to do this with USockets in Micropython for the Client code, the server doesn't print it to the shell. No error, return = sock.send(msg) returns the correct number of bytes. So something's working I guess, but can't figure out why the server side isn't receiving and/or printing.